# new to phonegap and strugling with phonegaps instructions

Tags: cordova

Hi all I'm new to phonegap and are following the instructions on this website

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

however when I run the command cordova platform add android, it throws the error ENOENT, no such file or directory C:.......

My application is running on M:...

Can anyone help

Im trying to run it on windows 7

thanks

Comment: it may help diagnostic if you put the full error not just the start. You can try to run the following command in a cmd shell and say what it displays : `%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\check_reqs.bat`

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by several issues. It may be in installation in `node.js` and in  setting path for `Android SDK`.

Please check this [Blog](http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html) and follow the steps very carefully. You will be able to solve your Problem

Comment: if u get any issue, let me know